# Yii2 filter with multiple relationship

Tags: yii2

I just learn and work with Yii2 and I was problem with filter in the LoanSearch model.

I have 3 tables, Customer, Person, and Loan.

for customerModel has relation:

```
public function getPerson()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Person::className(), ['id' => 'person_id']);
}
```

for LoanModel has relation:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id']);
}
```

**Purpose:**
In the loan gridview, i want to filter with person name while the Customer table
contain the foreign key of the Person.

Please help to guide me.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you declare public property $person and $cutormer for searching and add Filters for that on your search model e.g:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'person.name', $this->person])
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'customer.name', $this->customer]);
```

Also you should add  safe rule for this properties e.g:
  `[['person', 'customer'], 'safe'] on rules()` method

Comment: thank for your answer, but the Customer table has no field name, it contains only person_id, and I want to filter person_name of Person table in the Loan gridview. Note: Person model has no relationship with Loan model.